# How to use numba njit in simple python function?

Tags: python, numba

I created a simple function meant the take a vector and multiple the result along several matrices, in which k is just the length of B and C. What keeps happening is that the function gives the error:

```
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function dot>) with argument(s) of type(s):
(reflected list(reflected list(float64)), array(float64, 2d, C))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.

...

def calc(A,k, B, C):
<source elided>
x2 = C[i]
c = np.dot(b,x1)
^
```

I made sure to split up the functions into an easier to follow method:

```
@njit(fastmath = True)
def calc(A,k,B,C):
    b = A
    for i in range(k):
        x1 = B[i]
        x2 = C[i]
        c = np.dot(b,x1)
        D = c + x2
        c = np.tanh(D)
        b = c
    return b
```

Is there a good way to fix this problem? If so, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: could you share example values for `A, k, B, C`?

Comment: A is a simple vector 1xn. k is the length of vector array for B and C. It would be 1xn for A, k = 0, nxm which makes the new vector 1xm, then it goes through the next sample mxz to get 1xz. It returns the 1xz vector.

Comment: @TWCar There is no such thing as `vector` in Python. When asked for example values, people here will expect an example on how you call the function, such as `calc(1,2,3,4)` -> using Python objects.

Comment: Kacper, a vector is just a 1xn matrix. It would be np.zeros((1,n)).

Comment: When calling np.dot(b, x1), b is a list of lists and x1 is an array.
I'd start by passing both as arrays.
Without examples for A, B and C it's difficult to say much more.